# ENCRYPTBYCERT alternative for MySQL

Tags: mysql, encryption, certificate

Looking for a way to implement [ENCRYPTBYCERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbycert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in MySQL. I want to generate certs with a 24 hour expiration and use them to encrypt values in a table. If the data isn't retrieved in 24 hours, the cert expires making the data invalid (and will be cleaned up with a stored procedure). SQL Server has a great implementation of this but I can't find any way in the MySQL docs to do this.

Comment: asymmetric_encrypt()?

Comment: I'll check to see if I have access to MySQL Enterprise.